# How can I properly compose my POJOs using inheritance or another approaches?

Tags: java, oop

I have two POJO-classes with almost same fields, e.g.:

```
public class B {
private String string1;
private String string2;
// getters, setters, equals, toString
}

public class C {
private String string1;
private String string2;
private String string3;
// getters, setters, equals, toString
}
```

I want to compose them using inheritance and one remark, that class C can not extend class B from a business point of view, therefore I made one abstract class that contains same fields and is inherited by these classes:

```
public abstract class A {
private String string1;
private String string2;
// getters, setters, equals, toString
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends A {
private String string3;
// getter, setter, equals, toString
}
```

And question is it ok, that I have a class B and it's full the same with abstract class or there is better approach to implement that, maybe design pattern?
If you need any clarification please let me now, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you did is totally fine, it just takes advantage of inheritance, and that's all you need for.
In addition, I would just change the access modifier of abstract class's field members from "private" to "protected", so that all concrete POJOs will have direct access to those fields, like this:

```
public abstract class A {
   protected String string1;
   protected String string2;
// getters, setters, equals, toString
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends A {
   private String string3;
// getter, setter, equals, toString
}
```